# How to create a route with dash and underscore in silex

Tags: php, routes, silex

i've got a project in php-silex, but i beging with this framework.
I create some route but some doesn't work.
Here some exemple:

```
/*
**INIT HERE & SOME OTHER CODE
*/
 $app->match('letter-{letter}', function($letter) use()
 {
    echo 'With dash';
 });

 $app->match('letter_{letter}', function($letter) use()
 {
    echo 'With underscore';
 });

 $app->match('{other}', function($other) use()
 {
    echo 'Other view';
 });
```

If i enter /letter-a the output is 'Width dash' but if i enter '/letter_a' the output is 'Other view' and not 'Width underscore'.

I want to known why this happened and how to show 'Width underscore' ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that the routes: `letter-{letter}` and `letter_{letter}` resolve to the same route name, thus the second one overrides the first. The solution is to explicitly give the routes a unique name.

You can do that by using `bind`:

```
$app->match('letter-{letter}', function ($letter) {
    echo 'With dash';
})
->bind('letter_dash');

$app->match('letter_{letter}', function ($letter) {
    echo 'With underscore';
})
->bind('letter_underscore');
```

I'll open a ticket on the silex tracker to see if we can give an error when two routes with the same name exist. (EDIT: [done](https://github.com/fabpot/Silex/issues/215))

Answer (score 0):

I don't believe they allow that type of syntax, they are doing whild card lookups between your slashes'/' and taking the entire value, obviously they are not allowing true pattern matching.